# How to save the current User in models while posting?

Tags: python, django

How to save the current User in models while posting?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')    #Please tell me how to save the current user here
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: You can't do this in the `models.py`. You have to adjust the view, which you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

You view in your `view.py` file have access to user in `request` object

```
def save_post(request):
    # you have to fill all needed fields. It's just an example
    Post.objects.create(author=request.user)          
    return HttpResponse()
```